# How to make a Permanent redirect to an internal ip address with apache in Ubuntu?

Tags: apache, virtualhost, ubuntu-16.04, django-sites

I have the following problem: I want to redirect any request received on the external ip lets say 192.168.x.x, to an internal ip of the same machine, lets say 172.0.0.1. The internal ip has been associated to a name editing the hosts file as follows:

$/etc/hosts

```
...
...
172.0.0.1      www.example.com
```

I want to have www.example.com in the HTTP_HOST field of the request header unregarding to which external ip has been requested (In order to have django sites working properly without adding the current ip every time to the site list). Consequently I tried the following:

$/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName entrypoint.com
    Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com:443
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 172.0.0.1:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ...
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to connect from a browser the redirect seems to look for a web domain instead of the local ip. How can I fix this?

Comment: You are telling it to redirect to the URL in line "Redirect 301 / https:// www.example.com:443".

Comment: how can I specify that I want it to redirect to a local ip address?

Comment: Giving the local IP address instead of URL maybe?

Comment: Redirect 301 / 172.0.0.1:443?

Comment: Yes perhaps using the RedirectPermanent Directive. With protocol mentioned in the IP, so: RedirectPermanent 301 / https:// 172.0.0.1:443

Comment: Still not working due to ssl problem. Basically I need a proxy that redirects https request to the internal ip and send responses to the client.

Comment: Is the server listening to 172.0.0.1:443 SSL enabled?

Comment: Yes, if I comment the first virtual host and replace the <VirtualHost 172.0.0.1:443> with <VirtualHost *:443>. I am able to establish https connection from my LAN. The bad thing in this case is that  HTTP_HOST stores the external ip and I don't want this.

Comment: Try the virtual proxy server solution: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247343/redirect-subfolder-to-another-local-ip-in-apache

Comment: Still not sure on how to configure the virtual proxy :(

Comment: Can you please share what you see in Apache logs or chrome console?
Also Please edit your question with what configuration you are currently trying.